# Derivative $\operatorname{arccos}x +\operatorname{arcsec}\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus

My calculus text has this problem, but it seems to me that the inverse cosine and inverse secant functions do not share domains.  How can this function be defined?  Have a derivative?  What is something + undefined, or vice versa???

Comment: The function $1/x$ maps the domain of arcsec to the domain of arccos.  So you are OK.

Answer (score 1):

The arccosine is defined on the interval $[-1,1]$.  If $x\in[-1,1]$, then $1/x\in (-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$, and that is the image of the secant function; hence the domain of the arcsecant function.

Comment: Ahhh... yes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you don't know the derivative of $y = \mathrm{arcsec} x$, write $x = \sec y $, then $1 = \sec y \cdot \tan y \cdot y'$. Remember that $1 + \tan^2 y = \sec^2 y$ and obtain $$y' = \frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}$$
The absolute value that appears makes sense if you think of the graph of arcsec. Just for more information,  $\mathrm{arccsc}'x = - \frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}$. Then use a similar proceedure to find the derivative of arccos, and chain rule to solve your problem, if you haven't already (: